# Is there a way to get a warning in Powershell if my virtual environment is not activated?

Tags: python, powershell

Is there some kind of tool that warns me if I want to use pip when no virtual environment is activated? The only thing installed in my global python is pipx and I want to keep it that way.

I am using PowerShell in the Windows Terminal App, so it would need to be compatible with that.

Comment: Are you already using another environment management tool (e.g. conda)? `pip install` outside a virtual environment should give an "externally-managed-environment" error since 2021. See the table in https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/?ref=itsfoss.com#use-cases - does python installation fall under one of the "yes" cases?

Comment: @SoZettaSho No I am not. I think that error only applies to linux distro python installations? The PEP explicitly mentions, that it's about python installations which are managed by the distro. On windows however there are no "windows managed" python installations (except maybe the windows store one?). The reasoning for this PEP was afaik the problem, that the distro python installation is used by the linux system and some system level tools, so messing with that installation could lead to issues.

Comment: The motivation cited are conflicts between packages installed by distro package managers and pip. But the solution "that Python-specific package management tools should neither install nor remove packages into the interpreter’s global context, by default, and should instead guide the end user towards using a virtual environment" is not specific to *nix. Windows store python would probably fall under "pip install permitted", as would unpatched CPython

Comment: See the section https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/#marking-an-interpreter-as-using-an-external-package-manager on how to configure it; you can try adding a file named `EXTERNALLY-MANAGED` to the directory given by `sysconfig.get_path("stdlib", sysconfig.get_default_scheme())`

Comment: The example for what to put in the file is for debian (ie. referencing `apt install`), you could simply copy paste the (irrelevant to your case) error message or write your own

Comment: Make sure everyone has read access to the file, and you may need to relog or restart too

Answer (score 0):

Not really no, but I am also not well versed with PowerShell. Any Terminal app will display some sort of hint which environment it's currently in. As shown here:

https://medium.com/@astontechnologies/how-to-setup-a-virtual-development-environment-for-python-with-windows-powershell-4cd34b2f9f9b

What you could do is to write a start script for PowerShell which runs a command to activate a spefic environment on startup, in case that is applicable. If not, e.g. you have several environments, you have to do it manually or write some elaborate script that activates a given venv based on the current working directory.

Anyhow, what's the issue in case you forget it? I mean that happens to we quite often, but uninstalling a package doesn't take too much effort.

Comment: Well yeah uninstalling is not that bad, but it annoys me a lot if that happens. So my hope was that there is some nifty tool which I could just install which warns me. Also I saw something similar for vim some time ago (but unfortunately forgot where I saw that).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[PEP 668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/) tackles the problem of conflicts between dependencies installed in the implicit global context by proposing "that Python-specific package management tools should neither install nor remove packages into the interpreter’s global context, by default, and should instead guide the end user towards using a virtual environment." While the context is in linux, the solution is not.

The PEP also outlines how to [mark a python interpreter as being externally managed](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/#mark-the-installation-as-externally-managed); I have tested the following procedure in docker and verified that it works.

Determine the install location of your interpreter's stdlib by running (within python)

```
import sysconfig
sysconfig.get_path("stdlib", sysconfig.get_default_scheme())
```

Outside of python, navigate to the stdlib path and create a file with the name `EXTERNALLY-MANAGED` containing the text:

```
[externally-managed]
Error=Runnning outside of virtualenv
```

Without this file, you may `pip install` in the global context. With this file, `pip install` fails with the error

```
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> Runnning outside of virtualenv

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

Of course this is a fix only for your current python interpreter/version. If you want a more permanent fix you need to bother whoever maintains windows python to adopt PEP 668.